# Robocopy with 300,000+ files

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, robocopy

We have a network appliance for our shared storage. We also have a fax application that dumps faxes into a single incoming directory. We want to start archiving files older than X days. Currently, there are about 318,000 files.

I set up a robocopy task that uses the following flags:

```
robocopy \\SOURCEDIR\saved \\DESTDIR\saved\2014 /mov /minage:90 /LOG+:\\LOGDIR\_TransferLogs\LOG_%date:~4,2%%date:~7,2%%date:~10%.log /v /ts /tee /MT:32
```

When executing, the log file gets created with header data, but nothing else gets processed. I don't see any files moving and nothing other than the header information appears in the CMD window. I let it run for over twenty minutes and saw no progress. I figured we would see many 'too new' entries added to the log as it churned away.

Any ideas why it seems to just sit there and nothing happens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It started running...:

- It put the cpu between 70 and 90% for 20 minutes, i believe it was scanning every file and building a pseudo index.
- All of a sudden my CMD screen blew up with the logs of all the 'too new' files
- CPU came down to about 20% and is still running.